# How can I clear the Facebook Activity Feed plugin contents on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've installed the [Facebook Activity Feed plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity) on my website some time ago, while the site was in deep development phase.  The site structure and URLs within the web app have changed significantly since then, however Facebook plugin did good job to capture all users 'likes' and 'shares' including those referring to deleted resources. And these activities are still shown in the plugin, some of them with unpleasant errors (because there is no resource at referred URL to provide Facebook with nice Open Graph METAs).

What I would like to do is to **reset the plugin so it 'forgets' all previous activities**, however I can't find how to do this. Looks like the activity history is stored somewhere on Facebook side.

The natural answer to my question would be to handle all those URLs that lead to not existing pages, but due to number of reasons I can't do that.
Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete the content. The content is entirely controlled by Facebook. The problem is that all these activities are actually associated with user's accounts. Because you can't control the content of a user's account, you have no control over the contents of the activity feed.

The one thing you could do is to set the filter parameter of the activity feed.

"filter - allows you to filter which URLs are shown in the plugin. The plugin will only include URLs which contain the filter in the first two path parameters of the URL. If nothing in the first two path parameters of the URL matches the filter, the URL will not be included."

By using the filter parameter, you could set your feed to only include urls that you want and leave out the old ones.

Comment: thank you, Nathan, will try your suggestion. I realize that those activities are associated with user accounts. As of now, all users of my websites are beta testers whom I know so I asked them to 'unlike' the pages from Facebook to remove the records from Activity Feed as well. They did remove everything they could find on their profile in Facebook but some activities are still showing up. Guess that's a question to Facebook, though.

Comment: Nathan, I want to thank you again - your suggestion is what I needed, I'm not filtering all unwanted contents!